# My logo in nav isn't responsive, using flexbox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, nav

I'm trying to create a flex header with nav. However, my image doesn't seem to be responsive. As I'm minimizing the width the menu seems to act responsive but my logo image doesn't.

The image is a dummy one, when i set an image with these certain width and height (without adding any dimensions in  property i have the same issue)

How can i solve this?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 91px;
    background-color: #222222;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 17.22px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 280px;
}

li {
    margin-left: 35px;
}

 nav img {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 254px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Logo_brand_Adidas.png/800px-Logo_brand_Adidas.png" alt="Digital Wise Logo" width="404" height="91">
        
            <ul>
                <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="#">Hompage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi! try to set img{object-fit: contain;}

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Hello, well when i set the real logo, the issue is still on.

Answer (score 0):

Preserve aspect ratio:

```css
img {
  height: 91px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the code you need to add `height: 91px;` `object-fit: contain;` in logo image and set `max-width` for responsive you need to add `media query` I have mention in code so you can check it.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  padding:0 5%;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li {
    margin-right: 35px;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
}

nav img {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 91px;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:575px){
  nav{flex-direction:column;}
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Logo_brand_Adidas.png/800px-Logo_brand_Adidas.png" alt="Digital Wise Logo" width="404" height="91">
        
            <ul>
                <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="#">Hompage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```